Why cant abstarct be on the same page as the titel (using \documentclass[sigconf, 10pt, nonacm]{acmart})

The problem I'm facing is that when I use my code in the LaTeX template, it spans across two pages instead of staying within one. This causes formatting issues and disrupts the flow of the report. I'm trying to ensure that the content fits properly within a two-column layout without splitting awkwardly across pages:
code:
\documentclass[sigconf, 10pt, nonacm]{acmart}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\pagestyle{plain}


\usepackage{anyfontsize} % To support custom font sizes
\usepackage{lipsum} % For placeholder text, can be removed

%% The following content must be adapted for the final version
% paper-specific
\newcommand\vldbdoi{XX.XX/XXX.XX}
\newcommand\vldbpages{XXX-XXX}
% issue-specific
\newcommand\vldbvolume{12} %14
\newcommand\vldbissue{1}
\newcommand\vldbyear{2020}
% should be fine as it is
\newcommand\vldbauthors{\authors}
\newcommand\vldbtitle{\shorttitle} 
% leave empty if no availability url should be set
\newcommand\vldbavailabilityurl{http://vldb.org/pvldb/format_vol14.html}
% whether page numbers should be shown or not, use 'plain' for review versions, 'empty' for camera ready
\newcommand\vldbpagestyle{plain} 
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric, sorting = none, sortcites,firstinits=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\usepackage{setspace} %linjeavstand 

%Next generation electrocatalysts for the oxygen evolution reaction}
\begin{document}
\title{Title of the recearch paper}


\author{name}
\affiliation{%
}
\author{name}
%\orcid{0000-0002-1825-0097}
\affiliation{%
}
\author{name}
%\orcid{0000-0001-5109-3700}
\affiliation{%
}

\fontsize{11}{13}\selectfont


%\setlength{\parskip}{0.5em}
\settopmatter{printfolios=true}
\maketitle

\enlargethispage{2\baselineskip}

% Use twocolumn to control page layout properly
 \twocolumn[{%
%\vspace{-3em}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
\vspace{0.5em}

\noindent \textbf{ABSTRACT}\\
\justifying
This is where the abstract goes. It should be a brief summary of your work, highlighting the key points and contributions.

\vspace{0.5em}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
\vspace{1em}
}]


\section{Introduction}
\input{Introduction}

\section{Background}
\input{Background}

\section{Electrocatalyst Materials} 
\input{Electrocatalyst Materials}

\section{OtherTitle}
\input{OtherTitle}

\section{challenges}
\input{Challenges}

\section{Conclusion}
\input{Conclusion}


\newpage

\printbibliography

\end{document}


Please fix your compilation errors first and remember that we do not have access to the files that you \input, so please simplify your example and make it self contained.

Hint: the class loads natbib which cannot be used with biblatex. In general if you are writing for a journal, only a few of them supports biblatex. Once biblatex is removed, the errors will tell you that you haven't provided enough data for \maketitle for this class. Please never ignore compilation errors.

I dont understand, if i cahnge it, then the bib is not showing

\twocolumn always starts a new page. But with acmart you should not use a manually formatted abstract but an abstract environment before \maketitle. See the acmart documentation (currently section 2.3) for more information about the top-matter commands, environments and their usage.

I simplified your code pretty drastically and it appears that invoking \twocolumn after \maketitle forces a new page. As @caboha recommended, use the abstract environment per the manual.

Try this on for size.
\documentclass[sigconf, 10pt, nonacm]{acmart}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{anyfontsize} % To support custom font sizes
\usepackage{lipsum} % For placeholder text, can be removed
\usepackage{setspace} %linjeavstand 

%Next generation electrocatalysts for the oxygen evolution reaction}

\begin{document}
\title{Title of the research paper}

% % Per page 10 of the manual
\author{Segovia's Name}
\orcid{0000-0002-1825-0097}
\affiliation{%
    \department[0]{Department of Lunar Studies} % 0 is the default 12
    \thanks{Thanks}
    \authorsaddresses{Nowwhere Ville}
%   \titlenote
%   \subtitlenote
%   \authornote
%   \authornotemark
    \department[1]{John Doe Institute} % higher than 0
    \institution{University of San Serriffe}
    \country{San Serriffe}}
\email{noone@nowhere.com}    

\fontsize{11}{13}\selectfont

%\setlength{\parskip}{0.5em}
\settopmatter{printfolios=true}

\begin{abstract}
    Actually, the abstract should go here.
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\enlargethispage{2\baselineskip}

%% Use twocolumn to control page layout properly
%\twocolumn[{%
%   %\vspace{-3em}
%   \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
%   \vspace{0.5em}
%   
%   \noindent \textbf{ABSTRACT}\\
%   \justifying
%   This is where the abstract goes. It should be a brief summary of your work, highlighting the key points and contributions.
%   
%   \vspace{0.5em}
%   \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
%   \vspace{1em}
%}]

% % All \input lines are commented, because we don't have those files.

\section{Introduction}
%\input{Introduction}
Introduction

\lipsum[1]

\section{Background}
%\input{Background}

\lipsum[3]

\section{Electrocatalyst Materials} 
%\input{Electrocatalyst Materials}

\lipsum[4]

\section{Other Title}
%\input{OtherTitle}

\lipsum[5]

\section{Challenges}
%\input{Challenges}

\lipsum[6]

\section{Conclusion}
%\input{Conclusion}

\lipsum[7]

%\newpage

% % Not necessary for Minimum Working Example
% \printbibliography

\end{document}

